# I'm passing a QPixmap to QAbstractButton::setIcon instead of a QIcon, but I'm not getting an error...why?

Tags: c++, qt

Just trying to understand why I'm *not* getting an error here. The QAbstractButton's (well actually I'm using the QPushButton, but I assume it's the same either way) member function setIcon takes a QIcon argument...

The function looks like: `void setIcon(const QIcon &icon)` and I don't think it's overloaded. So why is it that I can call the function and give it a QPixmap as an argument, but not get an error?

This line: `PB->setIcon(QPixmap());`, where `PB` is a QPushButton object, does not give me an error and I just want to know why because I'm new to C++ and maybe I'm missing something more fundamental. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You don't get an error, because the `QPixmap()` argument you give to the `setIcon()` function implicitly converted to a `QIcon` object. Or, better to say, compiler implicitly creates a `QIcon` object out of a `QPixmap`, as the following constructor exists:

```
QIcon::QIcon(const QPixmap &)
```

Comment: Ahh okay thank you, I've seen this before! And can the `explicit` keyword be used anywhere during this process to make the compiler not make the implicit conversion? If so, where would the keyword go?

Comment: The `QIcon` constructor itself would need to be declared `explicit`.